# Adding items to a given topological sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph, graph-algorithm, topological-sort

There is producer-consumer graph. Topological sort for the graph is T.
I want to add additional nodes to the topological sort T, with changing order in T.  Here assumption is that consumer relationship of higher priority than producer relationship.

The solution I can come up with is:

```
For new node N:
    check the last producer in the T for which N is consumer. Let it be T1
    check the last consumer in T for which N is producer. Let it be I2.
    If I1 < I2, add N after I1
    If I1 > I2, add N after I1 -- I assumed that consumer relationship is much more important than producer
    If I1 is null, add N before I2
    If I2 is null, add N before I1
    If there is a cyclic dependency make it acyclic by removing a consumer relationship
```

Is there any efficient algorithm for this? Any use cases I missed?
Any help is highly appreciated?

Comment: "by removing a consumer relationship" How would you pick the relationship to remove?

Comment: At present I am going by naive solution, just break the consumer relationship of N with any node in cycle.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add Nodes efficiently to a Topological sort such as this one. It is necessary that a DFS be run on an addition to a Node into the DAG. Since a Topological sort is created by finding a Node with no incoming edges, the sort must be run when all nodes are present. Meaning that if a new Topological sort is needed then it is necessary to present a DAG in which all nodes needed to be sorted are present before running a DFS to compile a Topological sort.